# Message: Undefined property: login::$login_model

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I get error Message:

> Undefined property: login::$login_model

This is my controller

```
class login extends CI_Controller {
function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    if($this->session->userdata('username')){
        redirect(base_url('welcome_message'));
    }
    $this->load->model(array('login_model'));
}
function index(){
    $this->load->view('login');
}
function proses(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }else{
        $usr = $this->input->post('username');
        $psw = $this->input->post('password');
        $u = $usr;
        $p = md5($psw);
        $cek = $this->login_model->cek($u, $p); //in here error
        if($cek->num_rows() > 0 ){
            foreach($cek->result() as $qad){
                $sess_data['id'] = $qad->id;
                $sess_data['email'] = $qad->email;
                $sess_data['username'] = $qad->username;
            //  $sess_data['level'] = $qad->level;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'login berhasil');
            redirect(base_url('welcome_message'));
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('result_login', 'username dan password yang anda masukkan salah');
            redirect(base_url('login'));
        }
    }
}
}
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: login::$login_model
>
> Filename: controllers/login.php
>
> Line Number: 25
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\adminpmjb\application\controllers\login.php
>   Line: 25 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\adminpmjb\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: does your model file login_model.php exist in models directory?

Comment: show us your model code

Comment: Is your `login_model` in a subfolder of the model folder maybe? If that is the case you have to add the path relative to the model folder as well.

Comment: If you are just loading one model you don't have to issue an array you can just pass the name as a string. Further, the issue is because either your script is not in the models folder, properly named as `Login_model.php` and `class Login_model`

Comment: $autoload['model'] = array('login_model'); i add script and fix my problem. but now i get another error @Alex

Comment: The autoload method is the only place you can load a model as an array. If you just want to load the model in the controller you do `$this->load->model('login_model')` (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html). If you are getting another error you should edit your question.